# VS 2015 RC can't add new Nuget Source

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to add a new nuget source from the package source options of the Nuget package manager, but after saving the changes the newly added source doesn't appear on the Package source list when trying to find nugets.

I also tried adding it using the nuget console but got the same result, any help here?